# Query from one factory and use that to query into another

Tags: angularjs

using this code once the store is located I want angular to fetch the right store from the store list(Stores), but I cant work out how to input the store ID into the list of the stores query.

```
app.factory('Stores', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('/rest/stores/:id',{ id: '@id' });

});

app.factory('FindStore', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('/rest/locator/:input',{ input: '@input' });

});

app.controller('baseCtrl', function($scope, $http, Stores, FindStore, $location, $filter) {

    fetchStore($scope.locator);

    var id = $scope.store.id;
    console.log(id); //returns undefined
    $scope.myStore = Stores.query({id:id}); //fetch all the stores instead of one

    function fetchStore(input){

        $scope.store = FindStore.get({input:input});
        var id = $scope.store.id;
        console.log(id); //returns id
    }

});
```

I appreciate all your help, and thank you in advance

Comment: you aren't taking into account that these are asycnhronous operations. You must use callbacks to access the responses

Comment: I understand but how can I pass $scope.store.id into  $scope.myStore = Stores.query({id:$scope.store.id});

Answer (score 0):

`$resource` functions are asynchronous, and use promises to provide the result. So you need to use `FindStore` like this:

```
FindStore.get({input: input}).$promise.then(function(result){
    // print out the result of the query
    console.log(result);
});
```

Basically your code is trying to print out the `id` before the query has returned with a result. `FindStore.get` doesn't sit and wait for an answer, it essentially says, "Hey, can you please query the server, and run the promise function when you receive a result."

I suggest giving this a read: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

---

EDIT: If you want to use the result of one query as the parameters of another query, there are a few ways, but the simplest to explain is to just use the result inside your first promise result. eg.

```
FindStore.get({input: input}).$promise.then(function(result){
    // get the store id from the result (this is a guess and depends on how you setup your data
    var id = result.store.id;
    // use the id in the next query
    Stores.query({id: id}).$promise.then(function(storeResult){
        // do something with the store result
        console.log(storeResult);
    });
});
```

Notice how you perform one query, and when it returns a result, you use it to run the next query. The next query then becomes it own promise that runs the result function when that query has returned.

Now I have written the example for understanding purposes, however this is not a very nice way of writing promises. Please read about them, and read about them again, because if you keep doing js you will use them everywhere.

Comment: I do understand asynchronous nature of javascript and that my issue is related to it, but my problem is that I cant take $scope.store.id value and query something else with it. just to clarify now that i have $scope.store.id set in my function how can I take this and query something else with it. $scope.myStore = Stores.query({id:$scope.store.id}); or in your case how can I bring "Stores" resource into the promises of "Store"